# PHP form validation, uses Javascript for error messages

Tags: php, javascript, html

OK so I have an email form on **index.php**. I am using **mail_check.php** to validate that both fields are filled in. 
(*there are more that is being validated, but not included as it is not the issue*)

The main issue is that from the **mail_check.php** I want to be sent back to the **index.php** with a message in placed in the **div id="mailrespond"**. I have chosen both PHP and Javascript to achieve this.

**Index.php**

```
<div id="mailrespond"></div>
    <form method="post" action="mail_check.php">
    <span>Name: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" /></span><br />
    <span>Email: <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" /></span><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="registration">
    </form>
</div>
```

**mail_check.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['registration']))

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


if(empty($email) || empty($name)){ 
    // if email and name are empty
    //header ("location: index.php");
    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location.replace("index.php");

        function msg() {
            // creating elements are a safer method then innerHTML
            dv = document.createElement('div'); // creates a Div element 
            dv.setAttribute('class', 'error_msg'); // adds error styling
            txt = document.createTextNode('please enter your name and email '); // create the message
            dv.appendChild(txt); // place the text node on the element 

            document.getElementById("mailrespond").appendChild(dv);
            }
            window.onload = msg;

    </script>
    <?php }
```

The code goes on, but My issue is that I am not getting the feed back messages. I am a little new to this all - if you can help that would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: You are being redirected before executing function msg()

Comment: You cannot place a location.replace before any other code and you cannot assign a function to onload inside the function you assign onload

Comment: Did you get your system work **without** any javascript?

Comment: Not an answer, more of a suggestion. But http://jqueryvalidation.org is a great way to implement javascript validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup><---- @downvoter please leave a reason! Thanks</sup>

Try this (and don't call a form field *name*, please since a form can have a name too)

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mail respond</title>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("mailform").onsubmit=function(){
    if (this.fullname.value=="" || this.email.value=="") {
      alert("Please fill in name and email");
      return false;
    } 
    return true; // allow form submission
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="mailrespond"></div>
    <form method="post" action="mail_check.php" id="mailform">
    <span>Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" maxlength="30" /></span><br />
    <span>Email: <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" /></span><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="registration">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mail_check.php**

```
<?PHP 
  if(isset($_POST['registration']))
  $name = $_POST['fullname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];


  if(empty($email) || empty($name)){ 
  // if email and name are empty - only seen if JavaScript is turned off
?>

    <h3>You did not fill in name and email</h3>
    <p>please wait to be redirected or click <a href='index.php'>here</a></p>;
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://example.com/index.php" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload=function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.replace("index.php");
        },3000);
     }
</script>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: And here we go again. Downvoting without telling WHY!?

Comment: Thank you for the help mplungjan, I have edited my work to be similar to yours and it is working well. ps. I didn't down vote :S

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure you didn't - it really galls me when I write some code that I believe in, that someone who disagrees does not give me a chance to learn something new or to defend my suggestions or fix a typo or whatever gave reason for the vote.

Comment: And another downvote uncommented. People. What is wrong with you? If you disagree with a post, help the poster AND the asker by telling us what you disagree with!!! Fly-by downvoting is completely and utter useless

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting to index.php in the msg function, so it does nothing else.

You should do it by pure PHP, set a component in $_SESSION, redirect by PHP to index.php and in the index.php check if the component exists.

Comment: Thank you SkarXa, 

So Sessions are a little beyond me at the moment, are you able to give me a quick overview on how you would change the two files? Thank you in advance :)